# Group rows based in column value

Tags: python, sql, join, pyspark, google-bigquery

I have the following table

```
|ID | A | B | C |
| 1 | 10| 15| 20|
| 2 | 10| 14| 21|
| 3 |  9| 14| 22|
| 4 |  8| 13| 23|
| 5 |  7| 12| 24|
```

I need to identify which rows have the same value in A OR B OR C and group then into the same ID. Like this:

```
|ID | A | B | C | ID_REF |
| 1 | 10| 15| 20|    1   |
| 2 | 10| 14| 21|    1   |
| 3 |  9| 14| 22|    1   |
| 4 |  8| 13| 22|    1   |
| 5 |  7| 12| 23|    2   |
```

I am using BigQuery and/or pyspark. I tried to make a JOIN using OR inside the ON clause, but that works fine for small data, but when I applied in my full table with 200MM rows was very slow.

UPDATE
The code I have tried was

```
WITH
tb AS(
SELECT 1 AS ID, 10 AS A, 15 AS B, 20 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 10 AS A, 14 AS B, 21 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 9 AS A, 14 AS B, 22 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 4 AS ID, 8 AS A, 13 AS B, 23 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 5 AS ID, 7 AS A, 12 AS B, 24 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 6 AS ID, 81 AS A, 23 AS B, 22 AS C
)

SELECT t1.ID, MIN(t2.ID) AS ID_REF
FROM tb AS t1
LEFT JOIN tb AS t2
ON t1.A = t2.A
   OR t1.B = t2.B
   OR t1.C = t2.C
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Please show the code you used

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you add the row (6, 81, 23, 22), which ID_REF value do you expect?

Comment: If add the row (6, 81, 23, 22) the ID_REF will be 1. The column of ID_REF would be (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1). That`s because the value 22 in column C would group the new row with the first four rows.

Comment: But it does also group with the ID = 5 row, which contains 23.

Comment: No, the ID = 5 row contains 23 in column C and the new row contains 23 in column  B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This the closest I can get you.
For each ID you will get an array of IDs it was connected with up to two steps, if you want more steps you need to convert it into recursive CTE.

I introduced several other IDS to test for cases of no connections and connections with other then the main cluster.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION array_distinct(a ANY TYPE) AS (
 (select array_agg(distinct e order by e) from unnest(a) as e)
);
create temp table first_connections as 
WITH
tb AS(
SELECT 'a' AS ID, 10 AS A, 15 AS B, 20 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' AS ID, 10 AS A, 14 AS B, 21 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS ID, 9 AS A, 14 AS B, 22 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'd' AS ID, 8 AS A, 13 AS B, 22 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'e' AS ID, 7 AS A, 12 AS B, 24 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'f' AS ID, 7 AS A, 16 AS B, 99 AS C UNION ALL
SELECT 'g' AS ID, 17 AS A, 2 AS B, 80 AS C
), unpivoted as (
select *
from tb unpivot (value for feature in (A,B,C))
), connnections as (
select unp1.ID, unp1.value, unp2.ID as connected
from unpivoted as unp1
join unpivoted as unp2 on unp1.value = unp2.value and unp1.ID!=unp2.ID
), in_arrays as (
select
  ID,
  ARRAY_AGG(connected) as connected
from connnections
group by 1
)
select *
from in_arrays;

select a.ID, array_distinct(ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(ARRAY_CONCAT(a.connected, b.connected) )) as concat_connected
from first_connections as a
left join first_connections as b on b.ID in unnest(a.connected)
group by 1
order by a.ID
```